# TERADATA Compare tables for matches

Tags: comparison, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have a question in relation to comparison between tables.

I want to compare data from the same table with different filter conditions:

First Version:

```
select * 
from PPT_TIER4_FTSRB.AUTO_SOURCE_ACCOUNT 
WHERE BUSINESS_DATE = DATE '2022-05-31' 
  AND GRAIN ='ACCOUNT'
  AND LAYER = 'IDL'
  AND SOURCE_CD = 'MTMB'
```

Second Version:

```
select * 
from PPT_TIER4_FTSRB.AUTO_SOURCE_ACCOUNT 
WHERE BUSINESS_DATE = DATE '2022-05-31'
  AND GRAIN ='ACCOUNT'
  AND LAYER = 'ACQ'
  AND SOURCE_CD = 'MTMB'
```

As you can see the only difference between the two is the `LAYER =` `IDL` in first version and `ACQ`

I wanted to see which records match betweeen the two excluding the column Layer(Because they would always be different.

I tried to do an inner join, but it keeps running for very long:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
 ( select * 
   from PPT_TIER4_FTSRB.AUTO_SOURCE_ACCOUNT
   WHERE BUSINESS_DATE = DATE '2022-05-31'
     AND GRAIN ='ACCOUNT'
     AND LAYER = 'IDL'
     AND SOURCE_CD = 'MTMB'
 ) A
INNER JOIN
 ( select *
   from PPT_TIER4_FTSRB.AUTO_SOURCE_ACCOUNT
   WHERE BUSINESS_DATE = DATE '2022-05-31'
     AND GRAIN ='ACCOUNT'
     AND LAYER = 'ACQ'
     AND SOURCE_CD = 'MTMB'
 ) B
 ON A.BUSINESS_DATE = B.BUSINESS_DATE
AND A.GRAIN =B.GRAIN
AND A.SOURCE_CD = B.SOURCE_CD
```

Comment: The combination `BUSINESS_DATE,B.GRAIN,SOURCE_CD` is not unique and you get a many-to-many join. Do you want to match **all** columns but LAYER or just `BUSINESS_DATE,B.GRAIN,SOURCE_CD`?

Comment: Please give example data and example results. Learning to write a Minimal Reproducible Example will help you clarify the problem for both you and us, often help you solve the problem yourself, lead to better testing methodology, and ultimately make you a better developer ; [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because a join for your purposes would need a 1:1 relationship between the rows being joined. You don't appear to have that, and haven't given any example data for us to derive one.

For example:

- sample 1 has rows 1, 2, 3
- sample 2 has rows a, b, c
- your results give 1a,1b,1c,2a,2b,2c,3a,3b,3c

That's effectively a CROSS JOIN, which happens because the columns you're joining on are always the same on every row.

My advice would be to select all the rows in question and Sort them. Then visually see if there are any patterns you want to analyse with joins or aggregates...

```
SELECT * 
FROM ppt_tier4_ftsrb.auto_source_account 
WHERE business_date = DATE '2022-05-31'
  AND grain ='ACCOUNT'
  AND layer IN ('ACQ', 'IDL')
  AND source_cd = 'MTMB'
ORDER BY layer, and, some, other, columns
```